# Что такое Java EE?

Tags: java, java-ee

Изучаю Java SE для применения в вебе. Вот никак не могу понять, что за Enterprise Edition. C SE все понятно - набор разных библиотек, которые поставляются с джавой, компилятор там и все подобное.

Но Java EE - это какая-то загадка. Википедия говорит, что Java EE - это Java SE с очень хорошей спецификаций, способностью к масштабированию и все такое прочее. Но что действительно это значит ? Разве у SE плохая спецификация ?

В описании "для чайников" говорится, что Java EE - это Java SE с динамически меняющимися библиотеками. Это как ? Если имеется ввиду обновление, то и на SE есть Maven и все такое, зачем тогда EE ?

Еще часто говорят, что Java EE нужен для серверных разработок. Но зачем ? Сервлеты без проблем можно клепать и на Java SE. Для использования backend-сервера можно воспользоваться библиотекой Jetty. И все это SE...

Лично мне пока вообще не понятно, что происходит в мире Java EE. Может кто-нибудь привести пример использования или написать, чем EE действительно может помочь ?

Comment: Писать сайты можно используя JavaEE, там будут сервлеты(Java Servlet) тесно связанные с `.jsp` файлом) `.jsp` файл это почти что одно и тоже что и HTML) Я конечно не профи в этой сфере, но благодаря JavaEE я научился писать динамическо-меняющиеся сайты)

Comment: @KryTer_NexT писать сайты на java - имхо извращение. Все равно, что телепОртером картошку окучивать... Java для бОльшего нужен.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, например ?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Ну он захотел пример где используется JavaEE, я ответил) Да, согласен то что на Java можно делать больше чем сайт) Но все равно, это тоже дело)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, что вы понимаете под "сайтом"?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Что-то вы не то прочитали в википедии, или не так поняли. Википедия не говорит, что Java EE это Java SE.

Java EE - набор спецификаций и соответствующей документации для языка Java, описывающей архитектуру серверной платформы для задач средних и крупных предприятий. https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform,_Enterprise_Edition

Да, если вы напишите сервер на Jetty, это будет не Java EE (это будет чать Java EE начиная с 7-ой версии Jetty). Но Java EE это не одни сервлеты, туда входит JSP, EJB, CDI, JPA и куча других спецификаций (см. ссылку на википедию).

На практике, J2EE это базовый набор интерфейсов/классов/аннотаций, а уже имплементации предоставляют сервера приложений - WildFly, GlassFish, WebSphere и другие.

> Разве у SE плохая спецификация ?

Не плохая, это разные спецификации.

> В описании "для чайников" говорится, что Java EE - это Java SE с динамически меняющимися библиотеками.

Бред.

> Но зачем ? Сервлеты без проблем можно клепать и на Java SE. Для использования backend-сервера можно воспользоваться библиотекой Jetty.

Jetty это контейнер сервлетов, это грубо говоря реализация части J2EE (с 7-ой вресии поддерживает Servlet 2.5 API, с 8-ой 3.0). Также как, например, Weld одна из реализаций CDI. Вы это всё можете использовать по отдельности, можете все вместе. Можете взять N технологий J2EE и связать самостоятельно, получится кривенький-косенький сервер приложений. Хотя лучше всё таки взять готовый )

> И все это SE...

И Jetty это SE, и другие фреймворки это SE, да и половина классов Java это тоже SE. Если есть желание, можете всё с нуля писать.

> Лично мне пока вообще не понятно, что происходит в мире Java EE.

Советую прочитать от и до хотя бы одну книгу по J2EE.

> Может кто-нибудь привести пример использования или написать, чем EE действительно может помочь ?

Каждая спецификация из J2EE вам чем-то помогает, вы можете использовать их по отдельности или в комплексе, в зависимости от ваших задач. 
Например: CDI - удобная инъекция зависимостей, не нужно писать кучу лишнего кода или модулей для Guice, JPA - удобная работа с БД на уровне объектов, EJB - удобное написание бизнес логики, JAX-WS - поддержка веб-сервисов, сервлеты - обработка HTTP запросов и т.д.
Разрешите одному программисту использовать только Java SE, а второму Java EE и посмотрите за сколько они решат какую-нибудь задачу связанную с веб.

Comment: *Разрешите одному программисту использовать только Java SE, а второму Java EE и посмотрите за сколько они решат какую-нибудь задачу связанную с веб.* Выйдет примерно одинаково, если SE-программист возьмет Spring.

Comment: @Nofate Spring это не SE, также как J2EE не SE. Spring в данном случае это альтернатива J2EE.

Comment: Спорное утверждение.

Comment: Не спорное. Spring задумывался как легковесная реализация JavaEE. В данный момент перестал быть легковесным и натащил в себя ещё кучу всего помимо JEE, но принципиально ничего не поменялось.

Answer (score 8):

Java EE - создана на основе платформы Java SE и предоставляет набор технологий для разработки и выполнения переносимых, устойчивых к ошибкам, масштабируемых, надежных и безопасных серверных приложений.

А вот про отличие Java EE и J2EE, можно почитать тут:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/javaee-faq-jsp-135209.html#diff

Ну и собственно для большего углубления в Java SE - можно изучить схему, этим понять технологию и работу виртуальной машины:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index.html