# Не работает @Interceptors

Tags: java, java-ee, ejb, code-injection

Должно выводиться сообщение "ворк", но не выводится.

Код класса с сообщением:

```
package test1;

import javax.interceptor.AroundInvoke;
import javax.interceptor.InvocationContext;

public class Method1 {
    @AroundInvoke
    public Object inter(InvocationContext ictx) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Work");
        return ictx.proceed();
    }
}
```

Код класса, в который я хочу "вставить" код с сообщением:

```
package test1;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.interceptor.Interceptors;

@Stateless
public class Work {
    @Interceptors(Method1.class)
    void work() {
    }
}
```

ну и мейн:

```
package test1;

public class Test1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
     Work work = new Work();
     work.work();
    }
}
```

Comment: [Java EE](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform,_Enterprise_Edition) API локально (без реализации) работать не будет.

Comment: А можете более подробно описать проблему, или указать на источник?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Java EE API](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform,_Enterprise_Edition) это стандарт согласно которому происходит взаимодействие с сервером приложений. Реализацию предоставляет сервер.

Для того чтобы использовать Java EE API, в частности [@Interceptors](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/interceptor/Interceptors.html) нужно выполнять код в контейнере Java EE. Для этого нужно:

- упаковать EJB в приложение (например, WAR);
- развернуть приложение на сервере приложений, в ходе разворачивания сервер обработает аннотации и подготовит реализацию класса;
- получить от сервера экземпляр EJB (с помощью @EJB или @Inject);
- полученный от сервера объект будет работать в соответствии с API.

В коде будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
@Inject
Work work;

...
//обращение из веб-сервиса, приложения, другого EJB
work.work;
...
```

В приведенном примере локальный класс `Test1` создает объект класса `Work`. Аннотации обрабатывать нечему, соответственно работать они не будут.

- [Java EE Tutorial. Java EE containers](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/overview004.htm#BNABO)
- [Java EE. Википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform,_Enterprise_Edition)
- [Что такое Java EE](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/550945/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-java-ee)